# How to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, http

The desired URL is `https://www.mysite.com`

I'd like to redirect all the followng URLs to be like the above URL.

Bad URLs:

```
https://mysite.com
http://www.mysite.com
http://mysite.com
mysite.com
```

And if anything is trailing, like `http://www.mysite.com/photo/1` for the url to be redirected with the same path: `https://www.mysite.com/photo/1`

**Why**!
Cause i've installed SSL Certificate

I've used .htaccess with that code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.mysite.com/$1 [R,L]
```

but it always redirect all to `https://mysite.com` while i need it exactly `https://www.mysite.com`

so any help ~ thanks

Comment: It is not obvious why it should redirect all of the above URLs to `https://mysite.com` - do you see the same if you clear your browser cache and try a different URL e.g. `http://www.mysite.com/?abcdef`? Aside, if you are not limited to .htaccess, it is worth considering some of the recommended alternatives to mod_rewrite @  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/avoid.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```